# Spring Data JPA - one-indexed-parameters - property starts from 0 not 1

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I am working on Spring Boot JPA Pagination example. I already went through so many link like: [How to configure Spring boot pagination starting from page 1, not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884860/how-to-configure-spring-boot-pagination-starting-from-page-1-not-0) and found no promising solution yet. I'm not using Spring HATEOAS.

Below is rest endpoint I developed.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve All Students", nickname = "Find Students ")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "200"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Page<Student>> getAllStudents(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value="page") Integer page, 
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "size") Integer size,
        Pageable pageable){

    Page<Student> students = studentService.findAllstudent(pageable, page, size);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(divisions, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

[image]

**application.yml** file

```
spring:   
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test?currentSchema=Test_Owner
    username: postgres
    password: admin
    platform: postgres
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate: 
        default_schema: Test_Owner
        jdbc: 
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    show-sql: true

    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        page-parameter: page
        size-parameter: size
        default-page-size: 10
        one-indexed-parameters: true
      sort:
        sort-parameter: sort
```

**Note:** As per pageable object shown in screen shot doesn't start from Page 1 instead of 1.

Comment: Please let us know, what kind of object is `divisions`, where does it come from and what is the content?