# How to make spring data pagination starts from 1 and not from 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I struggle to make the spring data pagination begins from 1:

Here is my database configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= "myPackage",entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
          public class DatabaseConfiguration {
}
```

Whe I try to set the property :

```
spring:
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        one-indexed-parameters: true
```

Or add:

```
 @Bean
 PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer 
 pageableResolverCustomizer() {
    return pageableResolver -> 
        pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
 }
```

The pagination still begins from 0.

My spring boot version is 3.0.6 and I have this starter in the pom.xml
spring.boot.starter.data.jpa: 3.0.6

Do you have any idea how make spring data pagination starts from 1?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Spring boot pagination starting from page 1, not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884860/how-to-configure-spring-boot-pagination-starting-from-page-1-not-0)

Comment: No I have tried what is proposed but it stills not working

Comment: I guess you misunderstand how this config property works. a good explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120070/spring-data-web-pageable-one-indexed-parameters-true-does-not-work/59999787#59999787

Comment: also take a look at the config method description from official API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverSupport.html#isOneIndexedParameters()

Comment: you are right @AndreiTitov , than you, in fact I didn't pass pageable in web request